# Export Excel with multiple table using Laravel 7 and Maatwebsite

Tags: php, excel, laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I have to export excel by joining two tables but I can't understand the way to complete this I'll attach the screenshot of my tables and codes. Please help me to solve these issues.

Table One: Decoration

[image]

Table Two: Decoration Price

[image]

Sample Data

[image]

**Decoration.php Model Page**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Decoration extends Model
{
    protected $table='decoration';

    protected $fillable=['deco_print_type','deco_prod_code','deco_supp_code','deco_name','deco_logo_setup_charge','deco_main_type','deco_is_main_type','deco_weight_for_sorting','deco_priority','deco_is_shown_to_clients'];

    public static function getDecoration()
    {
        $Decoration = DB::table('decoration')
                    ->select('deco_print_type','deco_name','deco_prod_code','deco_priority','deco_rank','deco_logo_setup_charge','deco_is_shown_to_clients')
                    ->where('deco_flag','=','1')->orderBy('deco_print_type','ASC')->get()->toArray();


        foreach ($Decoration as $deco)
        {
            $decoPrice = DB::table('decoration_price')
                        ->select('decp_quantity','decp_quantity')
                        ->where('decp_print_type','=',$deco->deco_print_type)
                        ->orderBy('decp_qty_break_leve','ASC')->get()->toArray();
            //$Decoration[$i]=$decoPrice;
        }

        return $Decoration;
    }

}
```

**Exports/DecorationExport.php Page code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Decoration;
use App\Decoration_Price;

class DecorationExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings
{

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // TODO: Implement headings() method.

        return [
            "Decoration code",
            "Decoration name",
            "Main decoration",
            "Priority",
            "Rank",
            "Setup Charge",
            "Shown_to_clients",
            "A2",
            "B2",
            "A3",
            "B3",
            "A4",
            "B4",
            "A5",
            "B5",
            "A6",
            "B6",
            "A7",
            "B7",
            "A8",
            "B8",
            "A9",
            "B9",
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect(Decoration::getDecoration());
    }
}
```

**Decoration Route Function for download**

```
public function DecoBulkExport()
    {
        $decoration = new DecorationExport;
        return Excel::download($decoration,'Decoration.csv');
    }
```

**When I click the export button data file should become like this.**

[image]

Please Help me or advise me on how to do this